# PHP multiply values of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I've tried searching for this as I don't think it's that unique that no one has tried to do it. I just can't figure out the right keywords to search for to find my answer!

I have this array

```
array(
 0 => array(
      'oranges'=> 4.00,
      'apples' => 2.00,
      ),
 1 => array(
      'oranges' => 2.00,
      'apples' => 1.82,
      'peaches' => 1.2,
      ),
 2 => array(
      'oranges' => 2.20,
      ),
);
```

What I want to do is find the value of all the oranges values multiplied together so (4 * 2 * 2.20) and all the values of apples multiplied together so (2 * 1.82).
The amount of arrays of values is variable and the amount of values inside the arrays is variable.

Comment: start with a `foreach()` loop

Comment: I've got that far... It's a bit hairy when I get to a foreach inside a foreach and whether or not their is a previous value set or not... i.e. at array 1 there is no previous instance of 'peaches' and at array 2 only oranges exist.

Comment: I've given you an answer, next time post your code so we can see what you've tried so far!

Comment: @scottphpnewbie think outside of those inner foreaches, as sjagr has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though sjagr’s answer is the best solution possible, I have an alternative approach with [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) which requires only one `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "oranges" => 4.00,
        "apples" => 2.00
    ),
    array(
        "oranges" => 2.00,
        "apples" => 1.82,
        "peaches" => 1.2
    ),
    array(
        "oranges" => 2.20
    )
);
$_arr = array();
    foreach(array("oranges", "apples", "peaches") as $val){
    $_arr[$val] = array_product(array_column($arr, $val));
    }
print_r($_arr);
?>
```

The result will be:

```
Array
(
    [oranges] => 17.6
    [apples] => 3.64
    [peaches] => 1.2
)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/82322

Answer (score 3):

This uses a combination of `foreach`, `isset`, and your run-of-the-mill `if/else` statements.

```
$products = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($products[$key])) $products[$key] = $value;
        else $products[$key] = $products[$key] * $value;
    }
}

var_dump($products);
```

Should be self-explanatory since all you're doing is taking the product of all of the lowest level elements with the same keys.